# Ktor Interceptor Ordering for same Phase and overriding

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm currently trying to implement the following pattern with Features, Pipelines and Interceptors:

```
auth {
    limit(1) {
        get {
            call.respond("Cake1")
        }
    }
}
```

In both features, I use  this:

```
pipeline.insertPhaseAfter(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features, myCustomPhase)
pipeline.intercept(appTokenAuthPhase)
```

I'm having the following two issues:

1. When using PhaseAfter, the order is wrong. Auth should be called first, Limit should be called second. Why is Limit first? How can I prevent this? Note: It should always depend on the code sequence, first block should be executed first. For some unknown reason it works as expected with PhaseBefore. But this seems inconsistent. The methods put the Phase in place to other Phases, but perform no Ordering for the merge. How is this done?

**insertPhaseAfter**

> [Phase('Setup'), Phase('Monitoring'), Phase('Features'), Phase('Limit'), Phase('Call'), Phase('Fallback')]
>
> [Phase('Setup'), Phase('Monitoring'), Phase('Features'), Phase('Auth'), Phase('Call'), Phase('Fallback')]

**insertPhaseBefore**

> [Phase('Setup'), Phase('Monitoring'), Phase('Auth'), Phase('Features'), Phase('Call'), Phase('Fallback')]
>
> [Phase('Setup'), Phase('Monitoring'), Phase('Limit'), Phase('Features'), Phase('Call'), Phase('Fallback')]

2. I would like to delete Phase Interceptors.

```
rate(100) {
 route("/sub") {
   rate(5) {
     get("/critical") {
       call.respondText("Hello, World!")
     }
   }
   get("/profile/{id}") { TODO("...") }
 }
}
```

So for /sub/critical only the Interceptor with Rate(5) should be called, and Rate(100) should be skipped. Is this possible in the current architecture? I see no way to override the merge and delete all but the "last" interceptor for the Phase "Limit". The other "Limit" should stay in place for all pipelines without an "Limit" as a child. Other Interceptors (like Auth) should be performed as usual.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? :) I am now as well stuck with the part 2

Comment: @Josttie Nope. The github issue for 1st was never resolved (just moved to their internal tracker) and then I didn't even bother with #2. Imo ktor seems more like a proof of concept framework. Wouldn't use it for anything productive. But if you ever find it out, feel free to answer. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write you what I did for part 2. I am unsure whether it is sexy or not. Basically, when I add a new child to the route with my custom things, I count how many parents there are in the route already that have the same selector. Then I pass that amount into the interceptor, so I know what the nested position of the current child is.

```
 fun Route.test(
        message: String,
        build: Route.() -> Unit,
    ): Route {
        val testRoute = createChild(SimpleSelector("message"))
        application.feature(SimpleInterceptor).apply {
            interceptPipeline(testRoute, message, testRoute.countSimpleSelectors())
        }
        testRoute.build()
        return testRoute
    }
    
    fun Route.countSimpleSelectors(): Int = 
        (parent?.countSimpleSelectors() ?: 0) +
            if (parent?.selector is SimpleSelector) {
                1
            } else {
                0
            }
```

Then in the interceptor I will add as many phases as I have nested interceptors. But I add them in reverse order, which means that the last added interceptor will run first.

```
fun interceptPipeline(
    pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline,
    message: String,
    nestingCounter: Int,
) {
    pipeline.insertPhaseAfter(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features, Authentication.ChallengePhase)
    val phases = (nestingCounter downTo 0).map {
        simplePhase(it)
    }
    phases.fold(Authentication.ChallengePhase) { old, new ->
        pipeline.insertPhaseAfter(old, new)
        new
    }
    pipeline.intercept(phases.first()) {
        val call = call
        val simpleContext = SimpleContext.from(call)
        TestPipeline().apply {
            val subject = SimpleContext.from(call)
            println("original subject: $message, new subject: ${subject.someMessage}")
            subject.someMessage = message
        }.execute(call, simpleContext)
    }
}
```

Now the latest added interceptor in the chain will run first. All that is left, is for interceptors to add a context to the pipeline. This context can be whatever you want, so you can for example add a boolean to the context: isAlreadyHandled. The first interceptor can flip this after its done, and following interceptors can ignore then the pipeline.

I based this on top of: https://www.ximedes.com/2020-09-17/role-based-authorization-in-ktor/

and the accompanying github repo:https://github.com/ximedes/ktor-authorization

I used the same structure as there, just added the counting and the context. I hope this helps a bit!